# App Engine if elif else working on dev but not production

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7

When I run the following code

```
user = users.get_current_user()
if users.is_current_user_admin():
    loggedin = 'Admin'
elif user:
    loggedin = 'User'
else:
    loggedin = 'Anonymous'
```

on the development environment I get Admin when logged in as an Administrator, User as a User, and Anonymous when not logged in.  When on production I always get Anonymous.  Why is this not working?

Comment: What is the value of `users.get_current_user()`?

Comment: @Blender that returns an App Engine User Object.  [App Engine Users](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/users/overview), basically when a user is logged in it returns true.

Comment: Can you post more context code, ideally a short request handler script that reproduces the issue?

Comment: I don't think title should be if elif not working. ^_^, it looks more like the login issue. I would suggest you edit the title a little bit to get more help. basically no chance that if elif not working in python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with if/elif/else or users.create_login_url().  The issue is with App Engine not recognizing a logged in user on a http request when the user logged in with HTTPS with users.create_login_url().  I've created a new question on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10963629/app-engine-howto-maintain-login-on-both-http-and-https-with-users-service).  I believe it has something to do with how the cookie is being set.

The reason the code was working on Dev and not production is how the development environment handles HTTPS urls it remaps it to http and serves the request avoiding the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to log in via users.create_login_url()