# How can I upload a static HTML site on Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine

Is there any tutorial for this? 
I have 3 files in my project:

- index.html
- index.css
- index.js

Should be simple, but so far I am lost in huge GAE's documentation.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to call out each file individually in app.yaml as Mark suggests; instead, a simple handler like this will suffice:

```
application: myapp
version: main
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /(.*)/
  static_files: \1/index.html
  upload: .*/index.html
- url: /.*
  static_dir: static
```

Then put your site in a directory called 'static' under the directory containing `app.yaml`.

The first handler ensures that `index.html` is served up any time someone asks for a directory. The second handler serves all other URLs directly from the static dir.

Comment: Nick would you mind taking a look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10906696/app-engine-not-recognizing-logged-in-user-with-users-service) while your working on improving my code?  ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I don't really think that is what Google intends the service to be used for.  But if you really **need** to serve some static content that is simple.

You define an [app.yaml](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig) file like so:

```
application: staticapp
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /
  static_files: index.html
  upload: index.html

- url: /index.css
  static_files: index.css
  upload: index.css

-url: /index.js
  static_files: index.js
  upload: index.js
```

Then use `appcfg update .` (assuming your using Linux in the source directory)

Comment: Thanks. I am using windows GAE Launcher. However, I am now getting this error on deploy: Unexpected attribute '-url' for object of type AppInfoExternal.

Comment: You'll have to wait for a Windows user to help there.  This works on Linux, note I updated my answer because I needed to add threadsafe and api_version.

I tried using the Windows Launcher once and couldn't get it to work whereas it is dead simple on Linux.  *nix is really the best place to do web development IMO.

Also you will need to add a line to serve images if your application needs those. Let me know I can add it.

Comment: @Ognjen I just noticed your error.  You have `-url` what you should have is `- url` notice the space.

Answer (score 0):

I made a simple Go app that does this very nicely. http://yourdomain.com will serve up index.html and the rest of the pages are accessible at http://yourdomain.com/mypage.html

Here's the yaml:

```
application: myawesomeapp
version: 1
runtime: go
api_version: go1

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: _go_app
```

Here's the go program that will serve up all your static files at the root level:

```
package hello

import (
    "net/http"
)

func init() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", handler)
}

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    http.ServeFile(w, r, "static/"+r.URL.Path)
}
```

Then throw all your static files in /static directory, run goapp deploy and you're done.