# Optimizing a slideshow and an image gallery [GAE / GWT]?

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, slideshow, image-gallery

I would like to implement my own slideshow and image gallery (for a foto reporting website).
Is there a best approach or tehcniques (using GAE and GWT) related to :

- reducing the slideshow's loading time (a slideshow containing 30 images (960px * 780px) for example, should I load them all firstly and then let the user navigating ?)
- should I do scaling operation (the image's resolution is greater than the browser's one) on the server side or in the client side ?
- is there some know-well problem concerning the storage (if I have a lot of images) ?

If you have some advice or links about this topics, could you post them please ? Thanks you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Question 1:** preload vs lazy
**Answer:**  The more you load to start the longer it takes your instance to spin up and the longer and larger the bandwidth.  So in general you should probably use a lazy loader but prefetch the thumbnails and the next image.

**Question 2:** image scaling
**Answer:**  I suggest creating a scaled version on upload that you serve then allow the user to download the full size image.  Don't do this on the client again the bandwidth would eat you alive.

**Question 3:** storage
**Answer:**  Use the [blobstore/python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10924018/1352012) or [blobstore/java](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/) instead of db.BlobProperty because it saves money on storage and allows for files over 1mb.

Comment: would you please explain the workflow of how to create something like an image gallery with GWT and App-engine ?