# How to setup dynamic URL in GAE?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, url

I'm new beginner of GAE. I now hosting a website on GAE.
I  want to change the URL of http://abc.com/about.html to http://abc.com/about/
How should I do? Thanks.

Here's my main.py:

```
import webapp2
from google.appengine.ext.webapp2 import template
from google.appengine.ext.webapp2 import util
import os

class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        template_values = {}
        path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'index.html')
        self.response.out.write(template.render(path, template_values))

class About(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.our.write(template.render('about.html',None))

def main()
    application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([(
        '.', MainHandler),
        ('about', About),
        ])
    util.run_wsgi_app(application)

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainHandler)],
                              debug=True)
```

Here's my app.yaml:

```
application: nienyiho-test
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon\.ico

- url: .*
  script: main.app

- url: /about
  static_files: about.html
  upload: about.html

libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: "2.5.1"
```

Comment: Why don't you show use your `app.yaml` file and the code that implement your web handler.

Comment: Hi Adam, I've uploaded my main.py. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to change your route.  You didn't provide us with the code that creates your routes but if you basically serving a static HTML file then as @AdamCrossland comment states you can do that with the app.yaml file.

Your app.yaml file should look something like:

```
application: your_app
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
default_expiration: "1d"
threadsafe: True

- url: /about.html
  static_files: static/html/about.html
  upload: static/html/about.html
  secure: never

- url: /about
  script: main.app

- url: /.*
  script: main.app
```

You can also use regular expressions as @NickJohnson suggests [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10924018/1352012) you can remove the secure line if you wish but I use https in some of my apps and use that line to enforce  which routes are secure vs not.

main.py

```
import webapp2
from google.appengine.ext.webapp2 import template
from google.appengine.ext.webapp2 import util
import os

class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        template_values = {}
        path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'index.html')
        self.response.out.write(template.render(path, template_values))

class AboutHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.our.write(template.render('about.html',None)

#  Setup the Application & Routes
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    webapp2.Route(r'/', MainHandler),
    webapp2.Route(r'/about', AboutHandler)
], debug=True)
```

EDIT: 20120610 - added main.py and updated the app.yaml to show how to route the generated content.

Comment: Thank you Mark. I've uploaded with my app.yaml

Comment: Are you wanting a trailing /?  If so then you need to add it the the url as in `- url: /about/` for the webapp2 matcher to be able to match the route.  Also you need to add a route in your main.py file now that I am looking at it again.  I will update my answer with an example main.py to route the / and /about.