# Python model of Google Contact for appengine datastore

Tags: python, google-app-engine, database-design, gdata, google-contacts-api

I would like to save contacts on [AppEngine datastore](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/datamodeling#The_Model_Class) from the [Google API v3](https://developers.google.com/gdata/docs/2.0/elements?hl=fr#gdContactKind). I want to know what is the best way to store these data and especially if there is already a model!

Looking at [the sources of gdata](http://gdata-python-client.googlecode.com/hg/src/gdata/contacts/data.py), I found a very interesting beginning. But this is the modeling of the data only in python and not for the datastore.

**Question : Is this model already exists in python?**

If not:

**Question : What is the best way to start from scratch?**

Beginning example of a contact in Python :

```py
class Contact(db.Model):
    """
    https://developers.google.com/gdata/docs/2.0/elements?hl=fr#gdContactKind
    https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/datamodeling
    """

    content = db.Text()
    """atom:content Notes about the contact."""

    link = db.ListProperty(Link,indexed=False,default=[])
    """atom:link*   Links to related information. Specifically, atom:link[@rel='alternate'] links to an HTML page describing the contact."""

    title = db.StringProperty()
    """atom:title   Contact's name. This field is read only. To modify the contact's name, see gd:name."""

    email = db.ListProperty(Email,indexed=False,default=[])
    """gd:email*    Email addresses."""

    """etc..."""

class Link(db.Model):
    """
    Link
    """
    link = db.LinkProperty()

class Email(db.Model):
    """
    Email
    """
    email_address = db.EmailProperty()


class EmailImParent(db.Model):
  address = db.StringProperty()
  label = db.StringProperty()
  rel = db.StringProperty()
  primary = db.StringProperty()


class Email(db.Model,EmailImParent):
  """
  The gd:email element.
  """
  email =  db.EmailProperty()
  display_name = db.StringProperty()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think everyone is rolling their own.  It is easy enough to do, you can take a look at [AE-BaseApp/Python](http://ae-baseapp.appspot.com/python) and check out the code from the Github link.  I have some new code that will be updated in the near future that contains some improvements to the contact model.  (the updated code is currently broken due to hacking to get logins working on both http and https [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10963629/app-engine-howto-maintain-login-on-both-http-and-https-with-users-service))

Comment: I looked at your code but I have not found anything related to the Contact entity. Do you plan add the entities in your directory `/models/`?

Comment: Look in the UserProfile.py file.  It is what i'm using for a contact in this application.  I have created a class called ProfileCrud for some future api reasons that you don't technically need.  You could get away with just the definitions of that class if you don't think you will modify it much but you would need to add the user id variable into those definitions that they are inheriting from the call to ProfileCrud. There is also some performance improvements of not having the extra lookup for the class. I haven't benchmarked it yet to know if it is significant but you should be aware of it.